# How to read multuiple Queues with spring jmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-jms

I am working on a project in my company where we have a application that displays message from the queues **IBM MQ** and the user can select and do operation on that message like send them to other queue or remove them after inspecting them.

The problem is as the application is rest service we have to get all the messages in all the MQs once user hits the page in react application.

There will be different brokers as well. For example we have 50 Mqs and two brokers (all MQ are there in each broker) that means we have 100 Mqs from which we have to browse and parse the message into json and send the message to front end

Problem is the time taken currently is too long it takes 20 mins plus to read all the message

As I can not share the real code I have added dummy code

```
    public Object getAllMessage() {

//        Some list of mqs
        List<String> mqs = new ArrayList<>();

//        Some list of connection Factory
        List<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactoryList = new ArrayList<>();

//        Logic to read
        connectionFactoryList.forEach(c -> {
            CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(c);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);

            JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);

//            Tried this approach after reading some posts where we can use a single session 
//            and read all the queues using that session then move on to next Queue Manager
//            but it didnt help in performance increase
            jmsTemplate.execute(session -> {
                mqs.stream().parallel().forEach(mq -> {
                    Enumeration enumeration = session.createBrowser(session.createQueue(mq)).getEnumeration();

                    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
//                        process the message and add it to a List
                    }

                });
                return null;
            });

        });
    return null;
    }
```

What can I do to improve the performance, Can I run each mq read operation in a new thread using jms Template, Can Jms Template or session call be shared among threads?
can we cerate multiple sessions for single connection factory ?

Not experienced in multithreading any help or dummy code will help a lot.

The end goal io to have all messages from all MQ from all Queue Managers into a list taht will be sent back to the front end and the business team can do their operation

NOTE : Dont want to delete the message fro MQ just read it as per the buisness requirement, need the fastest way to read all the message

Comment: What is the purpose of letting the messages being sent to so many different queues, if it is only one single application which builds one single joined list of messages from all those queues? Would it make sense to change your overall queueing design to have only one queue as input to your application and let all message producers use this queue as destination?

Comment: Actually this application is basically like a one stop admin tool which takes data i.e. message from many differennt department and applications from the whole bank like credit processing, bank transfer, loan processing which are spread across organistion.
This application was built many years ago for managers and supervisor to over see the internal operations, now our team was given this project to improve the application and perfromace and port into newer srping version only thing is the perfiomance we are not able to get past 20 mins.